# SQLite Order By foreign table field

Tags: sqlite, foreign-keys, sql-order-by

I have two tables like following: (They have much more fields in reality)

```
Records (
    recordId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    dateTime TEXT
);

Alarms (
    alarmId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    recordId INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (recordId) REFERENCES Records(recordId)
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I want to get all Alarms sorted by `dateTime` of Record they are referring. I think it should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Alarms ORDER BY Records.dateTime DESC;
```

But I couldn't find any relatable example.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a join of the 2 tables:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Alarms a INNER JOIN Records r
ON r.recordId = a.recordId 
ORDER BY r.dateTime DESC;
```

Or a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM Alarms a 
ORDER BY (SELECT r.dateTime FROM Records r WHERE r.recordId = a.recordId) DESC;
```